# Laravel 5 / Eloquent - query filtering on belongs-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Let's suppose I have these relations in my DB:

**Product**

id |  name

**Category**

id |  name

**Product-Category**

id | product_id | category_id

---

I can easily build it using Eloquent's Models using "belongsToMany" relations:
Product has a "categories" public function called "categories" and Category has a "products" public function.

Now, I have a page where the user wants to filter all the products for a given category by clicking on the category name.

The program will pass the category_id to my Controller and now begins the problem.

I can easily do it "by hand" writing this code:

```
            $products = Product::query()
            ->leftJoin('product_category', 'product.id', '=', 'product_category.product_id')
            ->leftJoin('category', 'product_category.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->where('category_id', '=', 2);
```

But this would make the process of defining the relation in the Model class almost useless.

Is there a better way of making it, maybe using the ORM stuff?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereHas`:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
    $q->where('id', request()->input('category_id'));
})->get();
```

See [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks! The only thing I had to fix was the name of the where column since id was "ambiguous". I had to explicitly tell him to use category_id.